# When I post data with fetch post, I don't receive data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I have a problem with fetch post, I want to send data to an url but it doesn't work..

```
function TodoTaskForm () {
    const taskContentInput = useRef(null)
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch('/api/tasks', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({content: taskContentInput.current.value})
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="__component_todolist_form_container">
            <input type="text" name="task" ref={taskContentInput} placeholder="nouvelle tâche.."></input>
        </form>
    )
}
```

In my component, I'm doing this and in my express server :

```
app.post('/api/tasks', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log('request received!')
})
```

When I test, i receive the request but req.body return "{}" in my console, I don't understand, im using app.use(express.json()) but it doesn't work, I have even try to use body-parser but...
So please, I need help.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. A body parser which matches the data being send. You've switched from sending form encoded data to sending JSON. Note that [Express has built-in body parsing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) and does not need the separate `body-parse` NPM module.
2. A `Content-Type` header on the request which states what format the data is in so the correct body parser can be triggered.

Such:

```
app.post('/api/tasks', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log('request received!')
})
```

**and**

```
fetch('/api/tasks', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({content: taskContentInput.current.value})
})
```